# redirect with multiple parameter query strings htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I want to redirect an url with multiple parameters and rename the parameters keys:

From

```
 www.site.it/index.php?par1=1&lang=en_US
```

to

```
 www.site.com/index.php?parameter1=1&languages=en_US
```

I tried with this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} par1=([0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en_US
RewriteRule ^index.php site.com/index.php?parameter1=$1&lang=en_US [R=301,L]
```

But it failed.

Comment: lang is always the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} par1=(\d+)&lang=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://www.example.com/index.php?parameter=%1&languages=%2 [R,L]
```

`%1` and `%2` are references to the capture groups in the query string regex