# htaccess redirect to file

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a folder to a file, with its *query string*.
I saved .htaccess in: /subdir

I use OpenSpeedLite 17.16 which auto-read .htaccess files,
and I tried few links (below) but nothing worked so far.
I always get the *original-url.*

Please help - Thanks

**original-url:**
[www.example.com/tmp32108/subdir/?task=userFiles&pid=1&lang=en](http://www.example.com/tmp32108/subdir/?task=userFiles&pid=1&lang=en)

**new-url:**
[www.example.com/tmp32108/subdir/myfile.php?task=userFiles&pid=1&lang=en](http://www.example.com/tmp32108/subdir/myfile.php?task=userFiles&pid=1&lang=en)

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d   // I tried these too
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)  
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=([0-9a-zA-Z_]*) 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} proc=([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etime=([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} task=([0-9a-zA-Z_]*)
```

**tried this:**

```
RewriteRule ^(/subdir/)?$ https://www.example.com/tmp32108/subdir/myfile.php?lang=$1&pid=$2&proc=$3&etime=$4&task=$5 [L,QSA]
```

**and this:**

```
RewriteRule .+myfile.php?lang=$1&pid=$2&proc=$3&etime=$4&task=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Posts:

[htaccess rewrite redirect with parameters in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50650172/htaccess-rewrite-redirect-with-parameters-in-subfolder)

[redirect with multiple parameter query strings htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349603/redirect-with-multiple-parameter-query-strings-htaccess)

https://serverfault.com/questions/824949/htaccess-301-redirect-from-directory-to-file

Comment: `/tmp32108/subdir/task=userFiles&pid=1&lang=en` - This "original-url" does not have a query string?! Please confirm this is the actual URL and not a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, just changed.